# Questions on the adjustment of bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am writing a document with loads of references using `bibtex`. However, I want to change the style of how latex layouts the references in the document. Currently it looks like:

```
[1] Reference 1
[2] Reference 2
```

What I want to achieve are the following adjustments:

- Remove brackets `[ ]` from the reference numbering
- Enlarge distance between all references
- Add additional space between the reference number and the reference itself.

The result should look like:

```
1    Reference 1

2    Reference 2
```

I am new to LaTeX and when I googled for enlarging the space between the references I found solutions for `biblatex` rather than `bibtex`. Thus, I tried to get biblatex running and even though it looks not too difficult I never succeeded. Therefore, I was wondering whether one can achieve my wanted adjustments using `bibtex` or is t preferable to use `biblatex`? Furthermore, I want to change the style of how the references are printed. I haven't yet tried all of the available styles for `bibtex` but `biblatex` seem to have many more features for that. However, it looks pretty difficult to adjust everything by hand.

Comment: You need to give us a bit more information. The changes you request are not very difficult to do without using `biblatex` (although `biblatex` should just work if you have an up-to-date TeX distribution, but that's a separate issue.)  Can you edit your question to show a minimal document that produces the output you *don't* like.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to go, add the two blocks of code in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1 \hspace{0.3cm}}
\makeatother
```

This will remove the `[ ]` around the reference number and add some space before the name of the author. (You can customize this space)

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\adjustmybblparameters}{\setlength{\itemsep}{1\baselineskip}\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}}
\let\ORIGINALlatex@openbib@code=\@openbib@code
\renewcommand{\@openbib@code}{\ORIGINALlatex@openbib@code\adjustmybblparameters}
\makeatother
```

This allows you to change the spacing between two entries in your references list. To increase or reduce the space change the `1\baselineskip`. Note that the gap with `1\baselineskip` is already bigger than without these lines.

[image: Output of the reference list]